# DocuSign - EnvelopeViews : createCorrect param 'advcorrect' does not work

Tags: docusignapi

I tried with createCorrect api to add fields for the recipients.
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeviews/createcorrect/

According to the api description above, I got a url like
https://demo.docusign.net/Member/StartInSession.aspx?StartConsole=1&t=xxx&DocuEnvelope=xxx&advcorrect=1&a=correct&vt=1

The parameter advcorrect is directly set to 1 in the returned url,
but the signer still starts in the prepare screen instead of the tagging screen

Is there any other settings that I should set up to skip the prepare screen?
Actually, when I tried with the senderView, all the params work. So I do doubt it is a bug with the correctView API.
The SDK version is 3.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a documentation issue. The correct way is to change the REST API call by passing the `beginOnTagger` parameter which determine where you start. The URL query parameter is also wrong and should just be a. You either do `a=correct` or `a=tagger`.

Comment: Thank you Inbar for your reply. I made some investigations and found a new parameter "beginOnTagger" was added since SDK 3.21.0 version and by setting "beginOnTagger = true" can solve my problem.
Also, I opened a case and the support told me I could solve it by updating the query parameter from a=correct to a=tag.
I just tried today and both methods work as expected.

Comment: I updated my answer, thanks Arbor for following up!